# Extract Section number from Equation reference

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

How can I obtain the number of the Section in which an Equation (or Figure) appears? For instance, I have the reference **3.2**, which refers to the second (**2nd**) Equation in Section **3**. How can I extract the **3** (or the **2**), such that it is still clickable (using hyperref)?

Preferably it should return "2nd" when it is the second Equation, "3d" when it's the third one, and so on.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\section{Start}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Halfway}

The equation \eqref{ThisOne} is the (1st, 2nd, 3d, ...?) Equation in Section (1, 2, 3, ...?).

\section{End}

A famous formula:

\begin{equation}
x_1, x_2 = \frac{ -b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{ 2a }
\end{equation}

And another one:

\begin{equation}
\sin^2(\varphi) + \cos^2(\varphi) = 1
\label{ThisOne}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily with the help of the [`refcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) (to turn the reference number into a string), [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) (to extract the number before and after the dot), and [`engord`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/engord) (to get the desired format as ordinal number) packages.

In the following example, I defined the commands `\SecNum` and `\EqNum`; the first one gives the section number of the reference and the second one gives the equation number in ordinal notation and turns it into a hyperlink to the given equation:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{engord}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand\equ{}
\newcommand\EqNum[1]{%
  \StrBehind{\getrefnumber{#1}}{.}[\equ]%
  \hyperref[#1]{\engordnumber{\equ}\xspace}%
}
\newcommand\SecNum[1]{%
  \StrBefore{\getrefnumber{#1}}{.}\xspace%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Start}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Halfway}

The equation \eqref{ThisOne} is the \EqNum{ThisOne}~Equation in Section \SecNum{ThisOne}.

\section{End}

A famous formula:

\begin{equation}
x_1, x_2 = \frac{ -b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{ 2a }
\end{equation}

And another one:

\begin{equation}
\sin^2(\varphi) + \cos^2(\varphi) = 1
\label{ThisOne}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added `\xspace` from the `xspace` package to take care of proper spacing.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a very  nice solution. But for some reason, I'm unable to compile it (using PDFLaTeX): `! Missing number, treated as zero.`, `l.29 ...ion \eqref{ThisOne} is the \EqNum{ThisOne}`. For some reason, it expects another argument after `ThisOne`?

Comment: @Ailurus this will happen the first time you process your document with a new `\EqNum` command (the string for the reference has not yet been generated); press "q" when prompted and process the document again.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem (I had to run it manually, normally I use a shortcut within my editor). One other thing, why is there so much whitespace around `2^{nd}`?

Comment: @Ailurus problem solved! It was just some spurious blank spaces in the code that I've corrected in my updated answer.

Comment: Ah I see. Now I also know what the `%`-sign means at the end of a line. Thanks!

Comment: @Ailurus I just did a minor change with the help of the `xspace` package to manage spaces automatically.

Answer (score 5):

The [`zref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) allows for an extention of the regular 2-part `\label`-`\ref` system into any number of properties/elements. The following MWE creates a new property list (called `special`) and adds `section` and `equation` counters (in `\arabic` format) to this list for referencing:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref

\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{special}% Create a new property list called special
\zref@newprop{section}{\arabic{section}}% Section property holds \arabic{section}
\zref@addprop{special}{section}% Add a section property to special
\zref@newprop{equation}{\arabic{equation}}% Equation property holds \arabic{equation}
\zref@addprop{special}{equation}% Add an equation property to special
\newcommand*{\eqnref}[1]{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{equation}{??}}
\newcommand*{\secref}[1]{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{section}{??}}
\newcommand*{\spref}[2][section]{\zref@extractdefault{#2}{#1}{??}}
\newcommand*{\splabel}[1]{\zref@labelbylist{#1}{special}}%
\makeatother
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\section{Start}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Halfway}

The equation \eqref{ThisOne} is Equation~\eqnref{ThisOne} in Section~\secref{ThisOne}.

\section{End}

A famous formula:

\begin{equation}
x_1, x_2 = \frac{ -b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{ 2a }
\end{equation}

And another one:

\begin{equation}
\sin^2(\varphi) + \cos^2(\varphi) = 1
\label{ThisOne}\splabel{ThisOne}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`zref` labels are set using `\splabel`, while equations are referenced using `\eqnref` and sections using `\secref`. These are specific implementations of a more general `\spref[<type>]{<refname>}` (where `<type>` defaults to `section`). Since the macros used are expandable, [`fmtcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) can also be used to provide ordinal references:

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount
%...
\newcommand*{\eqnref}[1]{\ordinalnum{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{equation}{??}}}
```

[image]

Hyper-referencing is also possible, if needed.

---

With the addition of

```
\let\oldlabel\label
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1}\splabel{#1}}%
```

in your preamble, you only have to use one `\label` command to obtain the desired referencing output rather than `\label` + `\splabel`.

Comment: Thanks Werner, nice to see such different solutions for my question. The only drawback seems that one has to use a different kind of label (`\splabel`), such that it is not immediately applicable to an existing document.

Comment: I've updated it to make it more "immediately applicable." Now only a single `\label` works.

Comment: For the label redefinition to work with hyperref, one needs to take into account http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85956/redefining-label-and-ref-when-using-hyperref