# Macro to print number of chapter containing a certain reference key

Tags: cross-referencing, amsbook

I am writing a document with the `amsbook` class. I have defined a macro

```
\newcommand{\thmref}[1]{Theorem~\ref{#1}}
```

I would like to include the chapter number as follows: "(4, Theorem 2.7.6)", not just "Theorem 2.7.6".

So I need some macro like

```
\newcommand{\thmref}[1]{(\chapterNumber{#1}, Theorem~\ref{#1})}
```

with some definition of `\chapterNumber`. This command should accept a reference key like `thm:very impportant theorem` and print out the number of the chapter which contains it. I'm sure this must be very simple, but I don't know it. Can you help? Thank you!

--

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\newtheorem{thm}[subsubsection]{Theorem}
\newcommand{\thmref}[1]{Theorem~\ref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{Alpha}
\subsection{Beta}

\begin{thm} \label{thm:important theorem}
Blah blah
\end{thm}

\chapter{Second}

\section{Gamma}
\subsection{Phi}

\begin{thm}
Foo bar
\end{thm}

This follows from \thmref{thm:important theorem}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document. On the hand, isn't  a section number like `4.2.7.6`, i.e. with leading chapter number much easier? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks! I added an example. Yes, probably you're right, but I think its gets confusing with too many numbers :)

Comment: The problem is that the thm. number 1.1.1 is not coupled to the chapter number here! I've got another proposition: Use a different counter output for the theorem, i.e. don't use the full `1.1.1` scheme for `section.subsection.thm` number, but just `chapter.thm` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses the functionality of [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) to store the `chapter` counter value with every call to `\label`. It is extracted as part of a call to `\thmref`, setting the chapter number together with the local reference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage[user]{zref}

\newtheorem{thm}[subsubsection]{Theorem}
\newcommand{\thmref}[1]{(\chapterNumber{#1}, Theorem~\ref{#1})}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57831/5764
\makeatletter
\let\oldlabel\label
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{%
  \zref@labelbylist{#1}{special}% Special label
  \oldlabel{#1}% Old label
}
\zref@newlist{special}% Create a new property list called special
\zref@newprop{chapter}{\arabic{chapter}}% Section property holds \arabic{chapter}
\zref@addprop{special}{chapter}% Add a chapter property to special

% Extract chapter number; defaults to -1 if it doesn't exist (or on first compile)
\newcommand{\chapterNumber}[1]{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{chapter}{-1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{Alpha}
\subsection{Beta}

\begin{thm} \label{thm:important theorem}
Blah blah
\end{thm}

\chapter{Second}
\section{Gamma}
\subsection{Phi}

\begin{thm}
Foo bar
\end{thm}

This follows from \thmref{thm:important theorem}.

\end{document}
```

Construction of the above details stem from [Refer to theorems in previous chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57799/5764) where one can also condition on whether or not to add the current chapter number to a reference if the reference occurs within the same chapter as the label.

Comment: Wow, thanks!! For a while I couldnt understand why it wasn't working in my real example, then i realized the problem was with hyperref! Oh well, i took out hyperref and it works now, thanks :)

Comment: @texnoobgirl: Yes, [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) completely redefines the `\label`-`\ref` system. If you wish to have compatibility with `hyperref`, I'd suggest [asking a follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764).