# \ref, \autoref and hyperref expansion

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, expansion

I'm trying to write section numbers to a file with the `newfile` package.
In details, this MWE basically tries to write to a `.ref` file with lines like `A-B`. The `A` and `B` are generated by `\label` and `\ref` commands: if `\ref{A}` is written in section 2 and `\label{A}` is defined in section 1, then we should write `2|1` in the file.

This example actually fails to expand the `\ref` command, probably due to the insertion of the `hyperref` package, which makes `\ref` robust. How can one avoid this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfile}
\newoutputstream{refFile}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.ref}{refFile}

\let\oldref\ref
\let\oldAutoref\autoref
\usepackage[linktoc=all,backref=page]{hyperref}

%% 
%% Write SRC-DST of \ref to file
%%
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{%
    \def\val{\thesection|\ref{#1}}
    \addtostream{refFile}{\val}
}

%% 
%% Redefine \autoref
%%
\let\oldAutoref\autoref
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{%
    \oldAutoref{#1}
    \myref{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\section{S1}\label{sec:one}
\autoref{sec:three}

\section{S2}\label{sec:two}
\autoref{sec:one}

\section{S3}\label{sec:three}
\autoref{sec:two}

\closeoutputstream{refFile}

\end{document}
```

The current content of the `.ref` file is

```
1|\ref {sec:three}
2|\ref {sec:one}
3|\ref {sec:two}
```

but I would like the expansion of the `\ref` to give:

```
1|3
2|1
3|2
```

Comment: Check the answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85956/redefining-label-and-ref-when-using-hyperref?rq=1

Comment: I already tried to make it works with this answer, but I did not succeed. I get commands `\TheRealRef` that are not expanded in the output file.