# How to redefine \label, \ref and \pageref in a way compatible with varioref?

Tags: cross-referencing, grouping, varioref

In order to prevent conflicts with labels when gathering exercices from a database, I need to redefine the commands `\label`, `\ref` and `\pageref` to add a local prefix to labels. Unfortunately, the package `varioref` does not work anymore.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}

\newcommand*{\globallabel}[1]{global:#1}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origref\ref
  \renewcommand*{\ref}[1]{%
    \origref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }
  \let\origpageref\pageref
  \renewcommand*{\pageref}[1]{%
    \origpageref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }
  \let\origlabel\label%
  \renewcommand*{\label}[1]{%
    \origlabel{\globallabel{#1}}
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Example 1: figure~\vref{fig:example1}.

Example 2: figure~\vpageref{fig:example2}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Example 1}
  \label{fig:example1}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Example 2}
  \label{fig:example2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get

```
Example 1: figure 1 on page 1.
Example 2: figure on page 2.
```

instead of

```
Example 1: figure 1.
Example 2: figure on the next page.
```

In the log file, I found

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:example1' on page 1 undefined on input line 31.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:example2' on page 1 undefined on input line 33.
```

I've tried to redefine the commands `\vref` and `\pagreref` in the same way ; without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

It's a bit harder to redefine the names as you need to redefine both `\vref` and `\ref` to catch top level use but `\vref` uses `\ref` internally and things get double-prefixed.
It would be possible to open up the sources just to add the prefixes in the right place but easier is to use new top level names to add the prefix, then things work as expected as the prefix is just added once and the internal use of `\ref` uses the already prefixed key without prefixing it again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}

\newcommand*{\globallabel}[1]{global:#1}

  \newcommand*{\myref}[1]{%
    \ref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }
  \newcommand*{\myvref}[1]{%
    \vref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }
  \newcommand*{\myvpageref}[1]{%
    \vpageref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }
  \newcommand*{\mypageref}[1]{%
    \pageref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }
  \newcommand*{\mylabel}[1]{%
    \label{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }



\begin{document}

Example 1: figure~\myvref{fig:example1}.

Example 2: figure~\myvpageref{fig:example2}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Example 1}
  \mylabel{fig:example1}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Example 2}
  \mylabel{fig:example2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Also some internals of package `varioref` need to be redefined, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}

\newcommand*{\globallabel}[1]{global:#1}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%  
  \let\origref\ref
  \renewcommand*{\ref}[1]{%
    \origref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }%
  \let\origpageref\pageref
  \renewcommand*{\pageref}[1]{%
    \origpageref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }%
  \let\origlabel\label%
  \renewcommand*{\label}[1]{%
    \origlabel{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }%
  \let\orig@@vpageref\@@vpageref
  \def\@@vpageref#1[#2]#3{%
    \begingroup
      \let\pageref\origpageref
      \orig@@vpageref{#1}[{#2}]{\globallabel{#3}}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \let\origvr@f\vr@f
  \renewcommand*{\vr@f}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \let\ref\origref
      \let\@@vpageref\orig@@vpageref
      \origvr@f{\globallabel{#1}}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

Example 1: figure~\vref{fig:example1}.

Example 2: figure~\vpageref{fig:example2}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Example 1}
  \label{fig:example1}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Example 2}
  \label{fig:example2}
\end{figure}   

\end{document}
```

Result:

```
Example 1: figure 1.
Example 2: figure on the next page.
```

Remarks:

- Using the internals rather than `\vref` or `\vpageref` makes it easier to support the various syntax forms (star, optional arguments) of `\vref` and `\vpageref`.
- In the redefinition of `\vref`/`\vpageref`, some original referencing commands are enabled to avoid double prefixes.

### Patch for `hyperref`

- A nested `\globallabel` is avoided in `\vref` by disabling it locally.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newcommand*{\globallabel}[1]{global:#1}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\origref\ref
  \renewcommand*{\ref}[1]{%
    \origref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }%
  \LetLtxMacro\origpageref\pageref
  \renewcommand*{\pageref}[1]{%
    \origpageref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }%
  \LetLtxMacro\origlabel\label%
  \renewcommand*{\label}[1]{%
    \origlabel{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }%
  \let\orig@@vpageref\@@vpageref
  \def\@@vpageref#1[#2]#3{%
    \begingroup
      \let\pageref\origpageref
      \orig@@vpageref{#1}[{#2}]{\globallabel{#3}}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \let\origvr@f\vr@f
  \renewcommand*{\vr@f}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \let\ref\origref
      \let\@@vpageref\orig@@vpageref
      \expandafter\let\expandafter\globallabel\expandafter\@firstofone
      \expandafter\origvr@f\expandafter{\globallabel{#1}}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Example 1: figure~\vref{fig:example1}.

Example 2: figure~\vpageref{fig:example2}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}

\newcommand*{\globallabel}[1]{global:#1}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%  
  \let\origref\ref
  \renewcommand*{\ref}[1]{%
    \origref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }%
  \let\origpageref\pageref
  \renewcommand*{\pageref}[1]{%
    \origpageref{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }%
  \let\origlabel\label%
  \renewcommand*{\label}[1]{%
    \origlabel{\globallabel{#1}}%
  }%
  \let\orig@@vpageref\@@vpageref
  \def\@@vpageref#1[#2]#3{%
    \begingroup
      \let\pageref\origpageref
      \orig@@vpageref{#1}[{#2}]{\globallabel{#3}}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \let\origvr@f\vr@f
  \renewcommand*{\vr@f}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \let\ref\origref
      \let\@@vpageref\orig@@vpageref
      \origvr@f{\globallabel{#1}}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

Example 1: figure~\vref{fig:example1}.

Example 2: figure~\vpageref{fig:example2}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Example 1}
  \label{fig:example1}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Example 2}
  \label{fig:example2}
\end{figure}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I thought it a bit late at night for changing vref internals:-)

Comment: Thanks, but :-) the MWE does not compile with `hyperref` package. I replaced `\let` by `\LetLtxMacro` as [you said here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85956/redefining-label-and-ref-when-using-hyperref/85962#85962). But at compile time, I get: `TeX Warning: Reference 'global:global:fig:example1' on page 1 undefined on in put line 44.`

Comment: There is problem too with `babel` for french language. Replacing the active character ':' in labels with '-', or `\usepackage[babel,kerning=true]{microtype}` solve the problem.

Comment: @EricGuirbal: I can't reproduce the problem, if I add `\usepackage[french]{babel}` to both examples.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek: I get `Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> :`. [According to egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83798/cleveref-varioref-missing-endcsname-inserted): "The problem is that varioref and cref don't like babel shorthands in the labels." Putting `\shorthandoff{:}` in `\AtBeginDocument` is another solution.

Comment: @EricGuirbal: Perhaps you have an older version of `varioref`. There are fixes for `french`/`babel` in versions 2010/11/12 v1.4y and 2011/10/02 v1.4z of package `varioref` for LaTeX bug reports [`latex/4093`](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex%2F4093) and [`tools/4159`](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=tools%2F4159).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Ok, now I am working with TeXLive 2012. The MWE with your patch compile. `\vref` works perfectly but `\vpageref{fig}` has the same output as `page~\pageref{fig}`. Loading package `varioref` in block `\AtBeginDocument` make `\vpageref` works properly. But when I add `babel` for french language, Bada Boum !  `Missing \endcsname inserted.    <to be read again>    \penalty    l.47 Example 1: figure~\vref{fig:example1}  ?! Extra \endcsname.  \@ifundefined ...dafter \ifx \csname #1\endcsname \relax \expandafter \@firs...`

Comment: @EricGuirbal: Package `babel` activates its shorthands in `\begin{document}`. That disturbs packages that are loaded afterwards via `\AtBeginDocument`.