# Is there such a thing as `\sectionref{}`?

Tags: cross-referencing, sv-classes

My sections are labeled, for example, as "**5.3**," where the 5 is the chapter number and the 3 is the section number. Using `\ref{}` to refer to that section would produce "5.3"; however, I would only like it to return "3" (the § number only, without the chapter number). Is this possible? How?

Comment: You can follow the guidelines in [Extract Section number from Equation reference](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57194/5764). Specifically, [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) provides a neat interface to provide what you're after (in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57215/5764) it's `\secref`).

Comment: You tagged this question using [tag:svmono]. If this is for an article submission, I wouldn't bother with creating special references. Regardless, since you might be using a special setup, you should ... **always** ... create something that we can play with, like a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Is that too much to ask?

Comment: In fact, if it is for submission it is better *not* to do this as you will only annoy the copy editor.

Comment: @Werner: It seems there's a conflict with zref and svmono…

Comment: @Geremia: I can mock up a minimal example using `zref` and `svmono` without problem. Can you *please* provide us with something that replicates your problem?

Comment: It is very likely that you will get an Author Query from the typesetter/copy editor to specify the reference if you really going to use bare section refs. Apart from that your problem is not easy to solve unless you redefine the way section numbers are written into your aux-files. Anyhow, it would be quite helpful to know whether you need the section number for (real) cross-referencing or whether you need it to do stuff with it, like, say, creating a counter for a custom environment.