# add auto text to figure number

Tags: numbering, auto-completion

i would like add some auto text to figure numbers according to the (automatic) reference numbers.

a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is figure 1}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{This is figure 2}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{This is figure 3}
    \label{fig3}
\end{figure}

i want to get "figure (1)'de" when i write " figure (\ref{fig1})",\\
i want to get "figure (2)'se" when i write "figure (\ref{fig2})",\\
i want to get "figure (3)'te" when i write "figure (\ref{fig3})" 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{cleveref}` and `\cref{fig1}` etc. instead of `\ref{fig1}` etc., if you're using `hyperref` as well, include `cleveref` **after** `hyperref`!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: but he wants parentheses as well, so you may want to point out the cleveref commands that accomplish that.  I'd provide an answer, but..... ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Rather than having the word "figure" appear automatically, the main point of the question seems to be that the `de`, `se`and `te` endings should appear *after* the figure number. I don't think that `cleveref` will do this, at least not without some help.

Comment: @Andrew: It should be possible with `cleveref` `\crefformat` command as well, but you answered it already, so no need to add another answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ah, thanks, didn't know about `\crefformat`.

Comment: @Andrew: thanks. could you explain how to get this in a section numbered document, please? namely "1.1'de" "1.2'se" "1.3'te" .... "2.1'de" "2.2'se".....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the question, a suffix of `de`, `se` or `te` should appear after the figure number. I have defined a macro `\fref` that adds these suffixes automatically, assuming that the suffix should still be `te` if the figure number is greater than or equal to 3. As a bonus, the macro automatically adds the word "Figure" to the reference.

Here is the output:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand\fref[1]{%
  Figure~(\getrefnumber{#1})`\ifcase\getrefnumber{#1}\or de\or se\else te\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is figure 1}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{This is figure 2}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{This is figure 3}
    \label{fig3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{This is figure 4}
    \label{fig4}
\end{figure}

Reference for fig1: \fref{fig1}.

Reference for fig2: \fref{fig2}.

Reference for fig3: \fref{fig3}.

Reference for fig4: \fref{fig4}.

\end{document}
```

One caveat, this works with your MWE but if the figure number includes a chapter or section number, so that it looks like 3.4 for example, then this will need to be modified.

**EDIT**

As highlighted already the solution above will not work if the figure numbers include a section or chapter number. Following [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57194/extract-section-number-from-equation-reference), here is one way of dealing with this case:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\fref[1]{\IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{??}{Figure~(\ref{#1})`\addrefending{#1}}}
\newcommand\addrefending[1]{\StrBehind{\getrefnumber{#1}}{.}[\fignumber]%
  \ifcase\fignumber\relax\or de\or se\else te\fi}

\begin{document}

\section{Section with figures}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is figure 1}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{This is figure 2}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{This is figure 3}
    \label{fig3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{This is figure 4}
    \label{fig4}
\end{figure}

Reference for fig1: \fref{fig1}.

Reference for fig2: \fref{fig2}.

Reference for fig3: \fref{fig3}.

Reference for fig4: \fref{fig4}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. can you explain how to get this in section numbered document, please? namely "1.1'de" "1.2'se" "1.3'te" .... "2.1'de" "2.2'se".....

Comment: @mert I have edited the post to show what to do when figures are numbered within sections.